# How to implement Antizer in clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript

I am trying to use Antizer (https://github.com/priornix/antizer) in my clojurescript project, and cannot figure out where to/how to import the css file in order to make the UI elements appear as Ant.design elements.

This is my current require statement:

```
(:require [reagent.core :as reagent :refer [atom]]
          [secretary.core :as secretary :include-macros true]
          [accountant.core :as accountant]
          [antizer.reagent :as ant]
```

Comment: Usually you import a css file through an html file, often index.html.

Comment: Thank you for the advice; it put me on the right path towards solving the problem!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finally figured it out. 
The reagent template doesn't have a traditional index.html file; it has the handler.clj which creates the index.html whenever it is served.

To include the ant.d stylesheet, you need to go to the handler.clj file, and under the head function, add:

(include-css "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/2.13.10/antd.css")])

This will solve the problem.